# Abstract Method Error with Android ExoPlayer

Tags: android, android-studio, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am trying to make a stream play in an android project with Exoplayer. Unfortunately, I am facing this run time error.

ERROR:

```
2020-11-17 17:04:27.867 8662-8765/com.example.videoplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ExoPlayerImplInternal:Handler
Process: com.example.videoplayer, PID: 8662
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void com.google.android.exoplayer2.drm.DrmSessionManager.prepare()"
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.mediacodec.MediaCodecRenderer.onEnabled(MediaCodecRenderer.java:605)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.MediaCodecVideoRenderer.onEnabled(MediaCodecVideoRenderer.java:477)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.BaseRenderer.enable(BaseRenderer.java:92)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.enableRenderer(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1878)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.enableRenderers(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1856)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.updatePlayingPeriodRenderers(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1838)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handlePeriodPrepared(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:1734)
    at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:351)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
```

Module level gradle:

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.videoplayer"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.8'
    implementation project(':PallyconWVMSDK')
}
```

project level gradle:

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

gradle-wrapper-properties file:

```
#Tue Nov 17 13:51:14 IST 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-bin.zip
```

I have also tried by including `android.enableDexingArtifactTransform=false`, but did not work. I am unable to solve this problem. Can anybody guide me?

Comment: I have tried the same but still getting this when I run the unsigned generated debug apk.